# How to make this relationship in MS Access (picture)

Tags: database, ms-access, foreign-keys, primary-key, relationship

I need to connect id_player from table Players to player_score and player_assist in table Goals. The primary key must refere to these two. 
 
Is there any way how to do it? 
 
Access writes me "The relationship already exist". 
I will be grateful for every answer. 
Access screen - [Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruAZ3.jpg) 
Is this the correct solution? - [Possible solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4iRr.jpg)

Comment: As a query: Establish(create) two copies of the players table. alias one as Player_Score; the other as player assist.  Now in terms of an entity relationship diagram (ERD): the system shouldn't have a problem having the Players.ID_Player as a FK twice in the goals table; so long as both constraints have different names.

Comment: I added another image. Is it the right way?

Comment: For a query to work correctly: yes.  Since Goals has two FK references to Players, Players table must be listed twice.  As a rule of thumb: Each FK (Foreign Key) reference to a table must have it's own Join to that table.  Since Goals has 2 FK relationships to Players; players must be listed twice (with a different name/alias)  Access will automatically put TableName_# when additional copies are added for this reason.  If you "View the SQL" you'll see that 3 tables are involved and that players is aliased once as Players_1

Comment: Short answer yes; but you'll likely want to make the Players_1 join an outer join: Include all records from goals and only those that mach in Players_1; this is true if not all goals require an assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each Foreign Key reference existing in a table; a separate join must be made to the main/base table to get the related data.

In your case; add Players again to your query and join it to the Goals.player_assist; while joining Players to Goals.Player_Score.

As to why: The same join can't get both pieces of data as they represent different relationships to the players table.

in SQL this would look like:

```
SELECT G.*
     , PS.id_Player as ScoredByID_Player
     , PS.first_name as ScoredByfName
     , PS.last_name as ScoredBylName
     , PA.id_Player as AssistedByID_Player
     , PA.First_name as AssistedByfName
     , PA.Last_name as AssistedBylName
FROM GOALS G
INNER JOIN Players PS
 on G.id_Player = PS.Player_Score
LEFT JOIN Players PA
 on G.id_Player = PA.Player_Assist
```

Note we alias the field names from players so we know which is scored by and which is assisted by.  We also alias the tables for readability and because we have to copies of "Players" and for the engine to keep track of which table we mean; we have to have them "named" differently.

The reason why I LEFT join (outer)  the second time, is because not all scores have an assist; but all scores have someone scoring them.  So the first join to players can be an inner join but the second join may not have an assist; and we still may want to see details for all goals made.  If we made the 2nd join an inner one, we would lose all scores where an assist wasn't involved.

Comment: Heey, now I get it. Thank you for your answer and your time.

Comment: If this answer helped: be sure to upvote and/or mark the answer correct so others may benefit from the explanation.  Additionally the next time you ask a question, people are more likely to take the time to answer if you complete the process by marking accepted answers.  If you want to wait to accept to see if there's something better; that's fine too; but if this helps at least upvote it!